# Среда для Android

Tags: c#, vb.net, android, .net, ide

Где удобнее делать приложения на Android на .NET фреймфорке, Mono за 400$, или [VS-Android](http://code.google.com/p/vs-android/) на C++ не подходит, и желательно с визуальным редактором (форм, или как там окна в Android'е называются).

Comment: оно не понравилось средой, там нету "редактора форм (или как - то так)", а вообще, чем программирование на Android/C# отличается от WP7/C#.

Comment: Сильно конечно C# c Андроидом... Не знаю то ли смеяться то ли плакать

Comment: Ну, Mono же есть, так что чего тут такого + Android NDK, это не C#, но хотя бы C++

Comment: Ну если честно Java то поближе к шарпу, чем плюсы

Comment: Рассмотрите вариант с Flash Builder, на AS3 очень легко перейти c C#, редактор формочек крайне мощный.

Comment: @Barmaley какой то однобокий у Вас взгляд, смотрите шире, люди уже так [работают][1] вовсю.


  [1]: http://hantim.ru/jobs/8471-s-razrabotchik-android

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это шутка? Вы думаете, что есть еще вменяемые варианты писать на .NET кроме Mono? Скорее всего Вам придется подождать, и не факт, что дождетесь.
Мне интересно тут на форуме вообще кто имел опыт работы .NET/Android? Если да, то как оно?

Почему java (и как ide eclipse, например) не вариант?

И, кстати, насколько мне известно VS-Android это не .NET, а NDK

В eclipse есть редактор "форм". Но если честно, в нем я лишь смотрю результат (и то примерный, потому что не всегда весь контент есть, хотя для таких случаев можно "заглушки" поставить), а так на эмуляторах и на устройствах, что есть в наличии прогоняю.
Отличия, мне кажется, в принципе кардинально разные будут. Если вы имеете в виду c# to Dalvik byte code. Для родной VM может и похожее что-то будет.

Comment: В eclipse - редактор форм есть, а в MonoDevelop нету, Java не вариант по тому, что его запарно после VB.NET и WinForms осваивать...

Comment: Ну в том то и проблема, что знания WinForms там даже при наличии шарпа вряд ли помогут.

Comment: Ну вот... визуалбейсикеры полезли кодировать Android - пора однако менять платформу!

Answer (score 1):

Вставлю свои 5 копеек. Unity3D имеет WYSIWYG редактор, редактор кода - на ваш вкус. Сам код C# и JS. Подходит для android и iOS. Осталось только адаптировать ваш 2D интерфейс к жизни в 3D

Comment: в Unity можно писать и 2D...

Comment: Мастерское извращенство